# error during build: RollupError: Could not resolve "./routes/Router.jsx" from "src/main.jsx"

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollup

I'm encountering a Rollup error when attempting to deploy my project on Vercel. This error occurs during the building stage of deployment. I've included the relevant information below, and I'd appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

I am trying to deploy a project on Vercel, but I'm facing a Rollup error during the build process. Here's what I've observed:

Error Message:

error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./routes/Router.jsx" from "src/main.jsx"
at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24860:24)
at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24822:26
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

i tried several time with several methods but it remains same[this is the log while i was deploying on vercel in building stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7maft.png)

Comment: Do you have a file named exactly `./routes/Router.jsx` (relative to main.jsx)?

Comment: yes i import routes in main.jsx

Comment: Double check that the file is there. Verify casing, directory, etc. That's the only thing that can go wrong here.

Comment: "Could not resolve" means that the file wasn't found.

Comment: but everything is ok while i try to run in localhost